# iCloud photos gone forever or still there?

Tags: iphone, icloud

So my friend shared an album and photos with me on ICloud but they disapeared from my iCloud photos stream on my phone 2 weeks later.By the way she just told me she deleted the album today but does that means can't get it back and it's gone forever or are the pictures still on iCloud somewhere

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't make copies to your library, no; they are not available to you anymore, since she unshared the folder and you no longer have access to them.